# How to pack file using 7z with Delphi and show percent done?

Tags: delphi, command-line, process, pipe

When I run this from command line:

```
7z a 1.zip J:\test.mp4
```

I can see how much in % is done.
When I tried to run this from Delphi using CreateProcess and CreatePipe I got nothing until the file is packed. Then it displayed the final output from 7zip.

My code looks like this:

```
Stream:= THandleStream.Create(hRead);
try
  if not CreateProcess(nil, PChar(Cmd), nil, nil, 
                       True, 0, nil, nil, StartupInfo, 
                       ProcessInformation) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  repeat
    if not GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInformation.hProcess, ExitCode) then
      RaiseLastOSError;

    while Stream.Position < Stream.Size do 
    begin
      Stream.Read(C, 1);

      if (C = #13) then 
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
        S := '';
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      end
      else if C <> #10 then 
      begin
        S := S+C;
      end;
    end;
  until ExitCode <> Still_Active;
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

I don't want to just create a ZIP archive- I know there are nicer ways to do this in Delphi. I want to interact with a console applications. Output from many console applications can be processed with the code I posted, but it fails with 7zip- that's why I ask about 7zip here. What is so special about 7zip that its output can't be captured properly? How to capture output from applications like this 7zip?

Comment: Reading progress info from a command-line app that uses `stdout` is difficult. Is there a reason you're using 7-Zip from the command line to create `.zip` files? There are other options that are more UI friendly, like [TurboPower Abbrevia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia/), freeware with source. It's trivial to connect Abbrevia's zip compression to a progress bar, and if you're writing a console app there are events that will allow you to do so easily as well.

Comment: Making a ZIP file is rather an example than my goal. I want to know how I can execute various command line apps and capture the output. The method I mentioned works fine for some apps, just not for 7zip so I am looking for a better method.

Comment: Ah, got it. Your question is specifically about using 7-Zip from the command line and showing progress, but you really don't mean it; you mean something else. :) Please edit your question to ask what you really want to know then, so it's not misleading and doesn't attract answers that aren't applicable. Thanks. :)

Comment: I added a comment to my question which should better explain what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Tom you could take a look [here](http://www.delphidabbler.com/tips/61) on how to get the DOS output and adapt that to notify the progress when reading the buffer.

Comment: @Diego Garcia Code you linked to shows output from a console applications after the application completed the job. So even my code is closer to what I want to achieve.

Comment: I tried my code on arj, lha and wget and it shows a job status on the fly. Still no idea why it doesn't work with 7z.

Comment: Is 7z using something like curses rather than writing to stdout?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I checked 7zip source and it doesn't look so. But even if it did- there should be a way to capture ncurses output.

Comment: @Tom did you try to execute the 7z.exe with the -so switch ?

Comment: @DiegoGarcia The -so switch outputs compressed data to stdout instead of a file, so I don't see how this can help.

Comment: Sorry @Tom I've just looked at the command help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take a look at the plugin made by [progdigy](https://web.archive.org/web/20121108044021/http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=13)

Progress bar

```
 function ProgressCallback(sender: Pointer; total: boolean; value: int64): HRESULT; stdcall;
 begin
   if total then
     Mainform.ProgressBar.Max := value else
     Mainform.ProgressBar.Position := value;
   Result := S_OK;
 end;

 procedure TMainForm.ExtractClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   with CreateInArchive(CLSID_CFormatZip) do
   begin
     OpenFile('c:\test.zip');
     SetProgressCallback(nil, ProgressCallback);
     ...
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: But it uses 7z.dll not 7z.exe.

Comment: I don't think what I want to do can be done with 7z.exe. Seems that such programs cannot have their output captured properly. I am quite bored looking for a way to do this and 7z.exe is the only program I can't process this way. Progdigy's wrapper is quite fine, so I am accepting your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## CMD:

1. Archive the folder with the contents.

   - 7z.exe a "Data\UpdateList.zip" "UpdateList*"
2. Archive only the contents of the folder.

   - 7z.exe a "Data\UpdateList.zip" ".\UpdateList*"

## WinApi:

1. CreateProcessWithComLine_Wait(30000, L"C:\MyExcample\", NULL, L"7z.exe a \"Data\UpdateList.zip\" \".\UpdateList*\" ");

```
    DWORD static CreateProcessWithComLine_Wait(const DWORD dwWait, const PWCHAR szFolderPath, const PWCHAR szFilePath, const PWCHAR szComLine)
    {
    DWORD result    = 0;
    // ----
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory( & si, sizeof(si));
    // ----
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( & pi, sizeof(pi));
    // ----
    si.cb                   = sizeof(si);
    si.wShowWindow          = SW_HIDE;
    // ----
    DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;
    // ----
    int iRes    = CreateProcess(szFilePath, szComLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, szFolderPath, &si, &pi);
    if ( iRes != 0 )
    {
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, dwWait);
    // ----
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }
    else
    {
    dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
    result = dwErrorCode;
    }
    // ----
    return result;
    }
```

Comment: What is the question here?